# Int to CharArray in Python

Tags: python

So I need a quick way to convert **x to CharArray?**
Is there any way quicker?

```
x = int(input('User İnput: '))
a = str(x)
b = list(a)
```

Comment: So you want to convert `"123"` to `[1, 2, 3]`? Or to `["1", "2", "3"]`?

Comment: Why convert input to an int and back to string? Other than that, no.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you have is pretty much the fastest way to do it.

```
>>> list('abc') 
['a', 'b', 'c']
```